# GPU is on more then 50%

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I have a simulation I create on unity and I have an issue that when I build and run my project and open it on my UI menu(there is only some buttons), and for some reason my GPU is on more then 50%.
I tried to delete evreything on my scene and create a new camera and build it and I get the same result.
maybe it can be relevent but Im using URP.
this is my profiler from the build mode:

[image]

and this is my task manager:
[image]
[[image]][3[![]
]

this issue happen on other computers on the GPU1

[image]
someone have an idea what causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my own solution-
for some reason when I open the UI menu, Unity try to get the maximum FPS and this is why the GPU work hard.
my solution is to block the maximum FPS to 30 on the UI menu using Application.targetFrameRate and then on my game the FPS to default like that:

```
void Start()
{
   Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
}
```

and to change it to the default do that:

```
 void OnDestroy()
 {
    Application.targetFrameRate = -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

note: GPU 0 is your iGPU, the gpu part of your cpu (that uses the system memory as "video ram" btw.). The actual dedicated graphics card is used 33% in that screenshot.

The "Desktop Window Manager" usage can go to 100% sometimes, afaik this is a Windows bug. Please try to turn off the hardware sheduling here:

[image]

On win11, this is hidden behind an "advanced settings" button (hyperlink text button)

Then restart and see if the GPU usage is now lower.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, On another PC I have this issue on my GPU1, I edit my question with a new picture